# Using multiple verbs with multiple nouns

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

In a sentence which uses multiple verbs and multiple nouns, is there a way to logically show which verb corresponds to which noun(s)?

E.g.

> 1. I like to buy and eat fish and chips.

(Both verbs apply to both nouns.)

> 2. I like to drink and watch football and cricket.

(Second verb applies to both nouns. The first applies to neither.)

Do we have to rely entirely on context?

Comment: "Fish and chips", since it refers to a definite object, is a singular noun, so saying "both nouns" is not exact...

Comment: @Alenanno: True, but the same question would arise if *fish and chips* were changed to *sweets and cakes*.

Comment: @psmears: good point :D I was just referring to that, but I see your point :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sentences structured like the example - you are right, context (and pragmatics) are all: without any context to suggest otherwise, "buy" needs an object, so the object must be shared, and since "football and cricket" is not a suitable object for "drink", we understand the intransitive sense of that verb (*to drink alcohol*).

For situations where confusion might arise, there are plenty of possible strategies to make it clear what is intended, for example:

> I like to buy fish and chips and eat it.
>
> I like to drink and I like to watch football and cricket.
>
> I like to drink while watching football and cricket.
>
> I like to watch football and cricket and drink. *(here we assume the speaker doesn't like watching drink!)*

Comment: +1 I was wondering how you think this sounds: "I like to drink, and watch football and cricket."

Comment: @Tragicomic: That works well too :)

Comment: It seems that that corresponding content questions differ in acceptability: *What did you buy and eat?* is natural, but *What did you drink and watch?* less so. I wonder why?

Comment: @jyc23: Interesting...

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts "respectively" will resolve the ambiguity, but not in all (eg your second example), so it is not a general solution.

Comment: +1 Though *respectively* might be a bit too formal for the *football* sentence, it is generally a useful word in more complicated sentences of this type. You might consider adding an example sentence and explaining in brief how it works.